# Escape special meaning of # (double quote) in Apache commons-csv

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

HELLO printing in a double quote in .tsv file because of '#' like "#HELLO". I want to remove the double quotes when it writes to .tsv

current output -> `"#HELLO"`

expected output -> `#HELLO`

```
try ( CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(new FileWriter("data.tsv"), CSVFormat.TDF))
{
   printer.printRecord("#HELLO");

}catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the version of CSVCommons to 1.8 and below code is working for me...

```
CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(new FileWriter("data.tsv"), CSVFormat.TDF.withHeader("#default1", "default2").withEscape('"').withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.NONE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust format

```
CSVFormat.Builder.create(CSVFormat.TDF)
    .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.MINIMAL)
    .build();
```

Comment: Not working deprecated ...

Comment: @shreeshailayavitkar I changed to non deprecated version.